# Swift 3 | Get current project class in a CocoaPod

Tags: ios, swift3, cocoapods

I have a project "MyProject" which use a CocoaPod "MyPod", in PODFile I have :

```
pod 'MyPod', :path => '~/Desktop/iOS/MyPod'
```

In my project "MyProject" I have a class MyClass. I would like to do in my CocoaPod "MyPod" =>

```
MyClass.myFunc()
```

Of course the is not working since "MyPod" doesn't know "MyProject" but is there a way to do this ? Can I pass an instance of this class or something ?

TY

Answer (score 0):

You can create a public protocol in your pod, pass a type of something that implements the protocol to a method, and have MyClass implement it in you project.

So, in your pod:

```
public protocol MyFuncType {
    static func myFunc()
}

public func f(type: MyFuncType.Type) {
    type.myFunc()
}
```

MyFuncType implementation in you project:

```
class MyClass: MyFuncType {
    static func myFunc() {
        // implement
    }
}
```

Use method like this.

```
f(type: MyClass.self)
```

Let me know if you need a more elaborate explanation. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think you figured out what's my problem. Btw I can't use `f(type: MyClass.self)` since MyPod doesn't know MyClass ! Or did I mess up something ?

Comment: Well, you call `f` inside your project, not inside your pod. Your pod can only work with its own objects and types and the ones passed to it from the project that uses it. Protocol lets your pod know that a type has a myFunc method, but there is no way for it know about `MyClass` exactly, since its declared outside your pod. You just need to put all methods that your want to call inside your pod in a public protocol

Comment: Ok thanks I get it, my problem is that I will use many pods. All of them will need to call function f. I can't declare the protocol in all my pods and I also can't call f from project. I think I give up on this, I'm searching for days and I can't find a proepr way to do this. Thanks anyway ;)